# Alexa-Skills-kit: How do a get the in-skill-products a user is entitled to outside of an alexa session

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I have an Alexa-Skill and am building a Web-App for this skill. In the skill users can buy a subscription for an ISP and in the Web-App I need to know if a user is subscribed (is entitled) to that ISP. How can I do that and is it even possible?

### More information

- My skill's code (written in python using the Alexa-Skills-Kit SDK) is hosted as an AWS Lambda function.
- The Skill's database as an AWS DynamoDB. The Web-App I'm developing has access to that DynamoDB.

### My idea

- From the Web-App use the [ask-sdk monetization_service](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python/call-alexa-service-apis.html#monetizationserviceclient) to get the products the current user is entitled to.

### What I tried so far

First I tried invoking my skill's lambda function through the ask-sdk with a request for my skill's "getEntitledProducts" Intent. This intent stores the entitled products in the response's sessionAttributes.
The request I got from the alexa developer console test tab where I (successfully) invoked the mentioned intent. Here in the developer console it works without problem

```
request = {
  "version": "1.0",
    "session": {
        "new": True,
        "sessionId": "<same session id as in the request in the alexa developer console>",
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "<my-application-id>"
        },
        "user": {
            "userId": "<the userId i want the entitled products for>"
        }
    },
    "context": {
      "System": {
            "application": {
                "applicationId": "<my-application-id>"
            },
            "user": {
                "userId": "<the userId i want the entitled products for>"
            },
            "device": {
                "deviceId": "<same device id as in the request in the alexa developer console>",
                "supportedInterfaces": {}
            },
            "apiEndpoint": "https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com",
            "apiAccessToken": "<same token as in the request in the alexa developer console>"
        }
    },
    "request": {
        "type": "IntentRequest",
        "requestId": "<same request id as in the request in the alexa developer console>",
        "locale": "de-DE",
        "timestamp": "2021-05-07T18:40:53Z",
        "intent": {
            "name": "getEntitledProducts",
            "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
        },
        "dialogState": "STARTED"
    }
}
```

This "getEntitledProducts" intent uses the monetization_service to retrieve the ISP-status for the user:

```
locale = handler_input.request_envelope.request.locale
ms = handler_input.service_client_factory.get_monetization_service()
product_response = ms.get_in_skill_products(locale)
```

The last line is where I get the following error:

> The authentication token is invalid or doesn't have access to make this request

I understand why the authentication might not work, since I just copied the whole request out of the developer console. I suspect either `version.session.sessionId` or `context.System.apiAccessToken` are not valid (anymore?). But how do I get correct access tokens using the ask-sdk outside of a skill session?

---

Next I tried using the ask-sdk monetization_service directly in my Web-App Code like so:

```
from ask_sdk_core.api_client import DefaultApiClient
from ask_sdk_model.services.service_client_factory import ServiceClientFactory
from ask_sdk_model.services.api_configuration import ApiConfiguration
    
fac = ServiceClientFactory(ApiConfiguration(DefaultApiClient()))
ms = fac.get_monetization_service()
ms.get_in_skill_products("de-DE")
```

Here I get the following error:

[TypeError: must be str, not NoneType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl6Wy.png)

Because I didn't supply an "authorization_value" to the ApiConfiguration. But how do I get such an authorization value?

I tried to use the LwaClient as described [here](https://developer.amazon.com/de-DE/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python/call-alexa-service-apis-out-of-session.html#lwaclient), but here I don't even know what to use as the "scope" in the call to `LwaClient.get_access_token_for_scope(scope)` (where they used "alexa:abc" in the example). And I'm guessing the LwaClient is for something completely different (Account Linking).

---

At this point I spend about 8 hours searching for a way to find out if a user is subscribed to an ISP but I feel like I didn't get any closer to the solution.

Of course I could just update a "is_subscribed" value in the Skill's database everytime the user uses the skill, but what if the user doesn't use the skill for some time. Then this value is never updated and my Web-App would never know if the user is still subscribed or not.

I hope someone can help me. I've never felt so desperate about a programming problem, because it's kinda the first time I couldn't find a solution using Google and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer to this question on the [Amazon developer forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/239363/how-do-a-get-the-in-skill-products-a-user-is-entit.html).
Currently it is not possible to invoke the monetization service outside of a skill session.

Answer (score 0):

One possible but not the best approach can be the database solution that you suggested but with some additional data. When the user subscribes for the first time you can always save the subscription datetime in the DB and you know for how long the subscription is valid. Then you just have to play with datetime library to know wether the user is subscribed or not.

This will not be helpful if your skill is already running and is live, but if not then this can help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know for sure, that there is no way to get the entitlement status outside of the alexa skill (in my Web-App)?
Concerning your suggestion: You mean just save the date the user first bought the subscription and then add 30 days for the end time? But if the subscription is continued for multiple months, I wouldn't know the new end time, right? I feel like always adding 30 days if still entitled would end up not being very accurate after some time. Also I might not know if the user canceled the subscription if done outside of the skill, right?